# Simplest way to keep a NSInteger in an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am coding my first iPhone game with cocos2D. And I want to save the best score of the player (just an NSInteger) in the app. What is the best and simplest way to keep this information ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just 1 integer?

```
// write
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:theInteger forKey:@"bestScore"];

...

// read
theInteger = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"bestScore"];
```

(Usually games support top-10, and you'd want to box the NSInteger into an NSNumber, insert all 10 of them into an NSArray, and save the array.)

Answer (score 0):

You could save name/value pairs to a plist via NSDictionary. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.dbuggr.com/leothenerd/cocos-saving-data-file-nsdictionary/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use NSInteger and store it in your preferences or a private file.

Store in user defaults with:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];

Retrieve With:

```
NSNumber * highScore = [defaults objectForKey:@"HighScore"];
```